# Google map's timeline is missing

Tags: google-maps

I'm from Sri Lanka and recently I found out that "Google map's timeline" option is missing on my Google maps Android application and even on the website. I've heard that some countries don't allow for such services. But I've used it before. Is there any way of using this feature?